# Error When Configuring Microsoft Identity Platform inside Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, active-directory, azure-active-directory, publishing, microsoft-identity-platform

When Configuring Microsoft Identity Platform inside VS for my publishing profile, I am getting the following errors:

1. ****Failed to Update Azure AD app
2. Failed to configure Update Azure AD Failed to configure dependency
3. Microsoft identity platform identityapp.aad1****

Answer (score 1):

If you are added **`Read directory Data permission`** while configuring azure Active directory in visual studio

[image]

Add the **`Directory.Read.All`** permission to the your app registered under active directory through Azure portal.

[image]